# Login to different Azure Tenant with two buttons in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, azure

On an Asp.Net page I need to support login for two Azure tenants.
The idea is to have two separate buttons, each triggering the login to its own app registrations in the first or the second tenant.

I know that a multitenant App registration would be possible, but the client wont to have separate tenants.

There are many examples of how to login to a single tenant but I cannot find any for the scenario above.

Can you give me an example of how to select tenant1 or tenant2 in runtime?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by myself. The trick is to register two `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` with different `authenticationType` values, which are used in the code behind to call the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`.

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using TwoSSOProviders.App_Start;

namespace TwoSSOProviders
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // IdentityProvider are project classes 
        public static IdentityProvider TwoSSO1Poc => new IdentityProvider
        {
            AuthenticationType="SSO1",
            ClientId = "cid1",
            AadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
            Domain = "intactconsult.onmicrosoft.com",
            TenantId = "tid1",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44323/About"
        };

        public static IdentityProvider TwoSSO2Poc => new IdentityProvider
        {
            AuthenticationType = "SSO2",
            ClientId = "cid2",
            AadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
            Domain = "intactconsult.onmicrosoft.com",
            TenantId = "tid2",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44323/About"
        };

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {         
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                CookiePath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath,
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            });

            ConfigureOpenIdConnectProvider(app, TwoSSO1Poc);
            ConfigureOpenIdConnectProvider(app, TwoSSO2Poc);
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

        }

        private void ConfigureOpenIdConnectProvider(
            IAppBuilder app,
            IdentityProvider idp)
        {
            var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions(idp.AuthenticationType)
            {
                RedirectUri = idp.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

                 ClientId = idp.ClientId,
                Authority =  $"{idp.AadInstance}{idp.TenantId}",
                
                ResponseType = "code",
                Scope = "openid email profile",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (notification) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (notification) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                },
            };
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
        }
    }
}
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;

namespace TwoSSOProviders
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var owinContext = Context.GetOwinContext();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                return;
            }
            var redirectUri = "https://localhost:44323/About";
            if (Request.Form[btnLoginA.UniqueID] != null)
            {
               Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                   new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri },
                    Startup.TwoSSO1Poc.AuthenticationType); //Note the AuthenticationType
            }

            if (Request.Form[btnLoginB.UniqueID] != null)
            {
                Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri },
                     Startup.TwoSSO2Poc.AuthenticationType); //Note the AuthenticationType
            }

            if (Request.Form[btnLogOut.UniqueID] != null)
            {                
                var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44323/Login"
                };
                Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(prop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```